# A reference for the definition of Dirac delta function $\delta (\cdot ,\cdot)$

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, dirac-delta

Assume that $\mu$ a quasi invariant measure on a homogenous space $M$. Pick $k\in M$. The Dirac distribution $\delta_k$ at $k$ associated with $\mu$ is defined as the distribution such that $\langle \delta_k ,\phi \rangle\equiv \phi (k)$ for any text function $\phi$ on $M$. Equivalently, it is introduced as a "Dirac delta function" $\delta (k,\cdot )$ such that $\int_{M}d\mu (q)\delta (k,q)\phi (q)\equiv \phi (k)$.

My question is that: (1) what is the definition of $\delta (\cdot ,\cdot )$ itself? Could you please introudce me a reference for it?

(2) What is the difference between "Dirac distribution" and "Dirac delta function"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The function and distribution are the same. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: @CyclotomicField Thank you. I can't find the definition of $\delta (\cdot ,\cdot)$ itself.

Comment: $\delta(k,q)$ is just a "function notation" for the distribution $\delta_k$, there is no additional definition ... and for fixed $k$ and $q$, no meaning to $\delta(k,q)$.

Comment: It might help to know the history: Paul Dirac was a physicist. In physics sometimes you model mass (or other quantities) as a density $\rho$ defined on over a volume  $V$. The total mass is $m = \int_V \rho\,dV$. Other times, you model a set of point masses, and total mass is their sum $m = \sum_k m_k$. This requires two sets of equations, one for point masses, one for distributed masses. This is annoying from a theoretic viewpoint. Dirac introduced the delta function as a way to treat point masses as if they were distributed to get around this. For physicists, it was mostly an inuitive notion

Comment: It was a notational convenience not intended to be considered too closely. However, to mathematicians, this is anathema. Ill-defined concepts have a nasty tendency to harbor contradictions, so we needed a conceptually sound definition. Considering the delta function to be a distribution is the most common way of accomplishing this. But rather than trying to drag physicists kicking and screaming down our rabbit hole, we instead use their notation while understanding in our own minds what it "really means".

Comment: What you are calling here $\delta(k,q)$ is $\delta(q - k)$ in the notation found in the wikipedia article (which is far more commonly used).